# Posting questions on different Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, etiquette, cross-posting

I asked a question on [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and after not getting an answer for two days I asked the same question on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour). There I got an answer immediately.

Should I now delete my first question, or should I copy the answer back?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't copy the answers back; if the question is 100% on-topic on Unix.SE, then leaving it shouldn't cause any harm (though some appear to strongly believe that cross-site questions should *never* be "exact" duplicates, so you may want to make sure that isn't the case). Bottom-line: if the question is useful on the site where it is, leave it. If not, go ahead and delete it.

Comment: @zoop98 that seems to be the worst of all possible worlds to me. If I keep the question up, why would I keep the solution from other people who run into the same issue and find my question through google? for me, the whole point of the technology stack exchanges is to maximize discoverability of solutions; where the votes give a weighting of how common the problem is. (anyway, I deleted the original question)

Comment: That's a fair concern! My thinking is that both questions will give answers relevant to their respective communities. If they both get good answers, then it really doesn't matter which Google directs searchers to. If it doesn't, then Google seems to do a decent enough job of sending people to the more active/ upvoted one anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should delete it, and I think you should have deleted it from the first site before asking it on the second.

This avoids duplication of content in Q&As across the SE network of sites.